# Not able to automate loading of node at login

Tags: node.js, nvm

Have **.nvmrc in my home directory**. .nvmrc has the line '**nvm use 4.2**'
But on login, getting message **N/A: version "nvm use 4.2" is not yet installed**
But from CLI, when I run "nvm use 4.2", it is fine and says :
**Now using node v4.2.2 (npm v2.14.7)**
And Im able to use node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should just place the version number in the file:  https://github.com/creationix/nvm#usage

Try re-creating your `.nvmrc` file with only the version number (`4.2`) as the contents (omit the `nvm use` part):

```
$ echo 4.2 > ~/.nvmrc
```

Comment: I would backup your `.nvmrc` version before you start overwriting files.

Comment: The entire purpose of `.nvmrc` is to load a specific version of node.  It's clear what should be in the file.